# Exclude file with grunt concat-json

Tags: node.js, gruntjs

I'm using `concat-json` to merge multiples `json` in a single one. However, the target `src`  varies, meaning that I read from two different paths.
 On one of those paths, I want to exclude a specific file to not be included on the `concat`. On the `npm` docs I dont find anything related to exclude a file while merging.

This is how I specify different targets:

```
grunt.initConfig({
"concat-json": {
    "en": {
        src: [ "reports/*.json" ],
        dest: "reports/request.json"
    },
    "de": {
       //Here is where I want to merge all jsons but one in specific
        src: [ "reports/temp/*.json" ],
        dest: "reports/request.json"
    }
  } 
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify [exclusions in Grunt globbing patterns](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#globbing-patterns).

With the following configuration, the `not-me.json` file will be excluded:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    "concat-json": {
        "en": {
            src: ["reports/*.json"],
            dest: "reports/request.json"
        },
        "de": {
            src: ["reports/temp/*.json", "!reports/temp/not-me.json"],
            dest: "reports/request.json"
        }
    } 
});
```